# Set connectivity settings to android app

Tags: android, wifi, settings, connectivity

I have an app that uploads multimedia files to server by using DefaultHttpClient. But I would like only to restrict this upload capability to Wifi only. I have tried using ConnectivityManager but it affects my phone settings.

How do I write this in my code so that this settings only applies to my app and does not affect my phone settings? Thanks in advance.

Comment: call the upload task when wifi is available

Comment: Can you detail with `tried using ConnectivityManager but it affects my phone settings` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public class NetworkConnection
    {
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) 
    {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;

        if (connectivityManager != null) {

            networkInfo =
                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        }

        boolean b  = networkInfo.isConnected();

        boolean result=(b);

        return (networkInfo == null) ? false : result;
    }
    }

then you can call this class anywhere you want by :

if(NetworkConnection.isConnected(YourActivity.this))
{
//Wi-fi enable
}else{
//Wi-fi disable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ConnectivityManager conManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo nwInfo = conManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (nwInfo.isConnected()) {
    uploadFilesToServer(); //Your function
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) class, you could check if wi-fi is enabled:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
//wifi is enabled
}
```

and if so, perform the upload. I am not sure what you mean with `tried using ConnectivityManager but it affects my phone settings`

Comment: Oh, I meant that when I used ConnectivityManager. setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI), it turns on my phone's wifi settings. It wasn't exactly what I intended.